# Selenium SendKeys() with Chromedriver uses Clipboard Content instead of "@" Character in email adress

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to write an email-address into an input field using Selenium and ChromeDriver in C#. Nothing spectacular so far. But in case of strings, containing "@"characters it is sending the content of the clipboard instead of this character.

For example:
The Content of the Clipboard ist "####MYCLIPBOARDCONTENT######" Copied by Ctrl+C

Execution of the Lines

```
         var input = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
         input.Clear();
         input.SendKeys("abc@def.test");
```

Is leading to this in the UI

[image]

Can anyone confirm this behaviour? How to deal with it? I don't want to bypass this by some strange hacks.

Comment: Try to SendKeys "AltGr + Q" instead of "@"

Answer (score 0):

Use action chains to build "AltGr + Q".

```
var actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);
actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt); //press Alt
actions.SendKeys("Q"); //press Q
actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Alt); //Release key
actions.Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't want to use these hacks for such basic string operations.

But i found the issue by myself now. It was related to my language settings in Windows.
I was using 1. EN-US, 2. DE-DE, and 3. EN-HR. I removed the third one. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because a non us keyboard.

```
import pyperclip as pc

AtSign = "@"
pc.copy(AtSign)
AtSign = pc.paste()

print(AtSign)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).