# Unicode signs not sent to text fields in selenium-webdriver chrome

Tags: selenium, encoding, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue after upgrading chrome and chromedriver to version 87.
My info inserted into text inputs lacks 'weird' polish letters encoded in utf-8.

I'm using windows, node.js, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Executing:

```
await driver.findElement(By.id('firstname')).sendKeys('Beżowy');
```

sends only 'owy' to the text input.

The 'normal' letters work good.
On previous version of chrome(86) and firefox it was all OK.

Does anyone have similar problem?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element

Comment: could be a keyboard mapping problem where "ż" is mapping to backspace... though not sure why the output wouldn't be "Bowy" in that case.  (Polish keyboard?)

Comment: If so, see this post where Croatian keyboard cause paste for "@" symbol.  Fix was in language settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385485/selenium-sendkeys-with-chromedriver-uses-clipboard-content-instead-of-char

Answer (score 0):

Thakn you all for answers.

I solved the issue.

On my server- windows- I had only pl-PL keyboard layout.
After adding en-US - everything works great again.

Weird, since en-US doesn't even allow to input characters I was missing :)

Anyway, this helped.