# Send_Keys wont send the "@" symbol when i try to send an e-mail adress into a textbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a problem with selenium, where it doesn't send the e-mail address properly.
the text it sends looks like this: myemailemail.com

the code I'm using looks like this:

```
EMAIL_LOGIN = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
```

I tried putting the @ in a variable, still doesn't work.
I also tried to put the email itself in a variable, and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you are trying to invoke `send_keys()` too early even before the [JavaScript enabled webelements have completely rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233385/request-fully-javascript-rendered-html-source-from-a-website-and-find-all-iframe/47237075#47237075).

---

### Solution

You need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use `click()`, `clear()` and `send_keys()` in tandem as follows:

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.click()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.clear()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.click()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.clear()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  EMAIL_LOGIN = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']")))
  EMAIL_LOGIN.click()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.clear()
  EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys("myemail@email.com")
  ```

Answer (score -1):

It's because a non us keyboard.

```
import pyperclip as pc

EMAIL_LOGIN = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

Email1 = "myemail"
Email2 = "email.com"
AtSign = "@"
pc.copy(AtSign)
AtSign = pc.paste()

EMAIL_LOGIN.send_keys(Email1 + AtSign + Email2)
```

Comment: [Please don't repeat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627) the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72692324/354577) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72692204/354577) to multiple questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32065499)